# Non-blocking and reentrant dispatch queue with order of execution

Tags: multithreading, c++-cx, task-queue

I'm trying to implement my own dispatch queue to dispatch tasks in the same order they are added to a queue. The motivation for this is due to the lack of C++/CX support for dispatch queues for Windows runtime components. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771042.aspx) is the documentation I've been considering. I understand that this is related to the [Producer-consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem), but I haven't managed to solved it using C++/CX yet. Given this, I've tried several approaches to this problem.

According to several examples and documentation I found online, I tried using semaphores to solve this problem. For that, I created a `DispatchQueue` class that holds several attributes:

```
namespace Threading
{
    ref class DispatchQueue
    {

    private:
        typedef IMap<String^, DispatchQueue^> MapType;
        typedef std::function<void()> TaskType;
        typedef std::queue<TaskType> QueueType;

    internal:

        static DispatchQueue^ Get();

        void Add(TaskType task);

    private:
        TaskType DequeueTask();
        void Runner();

        QueueType & GetQueue();
        const QueueType & GetQueue() const;

    private:
        QueueType _queue;
        std::mutex _queue_mux;
        std::mutex _add_mux;
        HANDLE _emptySemaphore;
        HANDLE _fullSemaphore;
    };
}
```

(Note: I'm not posting the actual code because the class has been largely iterated, and it's quite messy now. Let me know if you need other details.)

Here's how the semaphores are being initialized; at least that's the relevant part of the constructor:

```
Threading::DispatchQueue::DispatchQueue(String^ identifier)
    : _queue(),_emptySemaphore(CreateSemaphore(NULL, 1, 1, NULL)), _fullSemaphore(CreateSemaphore(NULL, 0, 1, NULL))
{
}
```

Here's my producer:

```
void Threading::DispatchQueue::Add(TaskType task)
{
    // Prevent different threads from entering this method
    // Disregard the mutex being static
    static std::mutex mux;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mux);

    WaitForSingleObject(_emptySemaphore, INFINITE);
    {
        // Prevent concorrent access to the queue
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_queue_mux);
        GetQueue().push(task);
    }
    ReleaseSemaphore(_fullSemaphore, 1, NULL);
}
```

Here's the consumer:

```
void Threading::DispatchQueue::Runner()
{
    while (true)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(_fullSemaphore, INFINITE);

        TaskType task = DequeueTask();

        task();

        if (!ReleaseSemaphore(
            _emptySemaphore,
            1,
            NULL)) {
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried dispatching the task (`task();`) *after* the semaphore has been released, but it didn't work either. It's also noticeable that `Runner` (the consumer) is started at an initialization point:

```
    create_task([dispatchQueue]() {

        dispatchQueue->Runner();
    });
```

The problem with this approach is that calling `task();` may also produce new tasks (`TaskType`), but this does not seem to be reentrant. As such, the implementation blocks. The lock happens because the task enters the `Add` method without having released the semaphore.

I've iterated and tried this producer instead:

```
void Threading::DispatchQueue::Add(TaskType task)
{
    create_task([this, task]()
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(_emptySemaphore, INFINITE);
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_queue_mux);
            GetQueue().push(task);
        }
        ReleaseSemaphore(_fullSemaphore, 1, NULL);

    }).wait();   // Notice we're waiting
}
```

The motivation behind that `wait()` is to guarantee that the tasks are inserted into the queue in the right order. This does work, but crashes if this method is called from the UI thread. This is not an option. Also, not waiting is not an option because, again, the tasks are not dispatched in the right order.

I've also tried [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Producer-Consumer-inter-cd30193b#content), which also blocks.

In short, I need a dispatch queue that respects the order of insertion without blocking the producing thread, as it can be main thread. Is there a fix for any of these approaches or any other approach you'd recommend?

Comment: Lots of text, and the problem statement essentially boils down to *"it didn't work"*. Also, what I don't understand, what's the rationale for creating a semaphore with a maximum count of 1? Why not use a mutex then?

Comment: I've read in several places (e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem)) that this problem cannot be solved using mutexes. Still, I only want to dispatch a single task at a time.

Comment: Mutexes and binary semaphores serve different purposes. However, the way you are using the binary semaphore, it could be replaced with a mutex and expose the very same behavior. I was just curious if there's more to it.

Comment: Not really. The code has just been iterated a lot. We started with the full and empty semaphores, according to the paradigm in the links.